# hypothesis test using a confidence interval

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval

i need to test the hypothesis that a proportion is greater than 0.93 using a confidence interval. i cannot figure out how to do this. the basic information that i think i need to use is below. the underlying variable follows a binomial distribution.

$$\hat p = 0.95, p = 0.93, n = 100, \sigma = 0.4$$

i have already tried constructing a confidence interval for a proportion using the Z distribution, but the upper bound is larger than 1, which seems wrong.

any advice for what i should do?

Comment: So how did you construct this C.I. and what exactly did you get?

Comment: p hat +/- margin of error = (0.872, 1.028) @imranfat

Comment: Doing a hypothesis test based on a C.I. is in my view not the preferred method, but it can be done. The thing is that since your SD is relatively high and your $p$ sample is quite close to $1$, the upper limit now exceeds $1$. You need to cut it off at $1$.

Comment: @imranfat and since the CI contains the null, i would fail to reject, right?

Answer (score 3):

The problem of your exercise is that the data are NOT coherent.

Substitute the given $\sigma=0.4$ with its estimation $\hat{\sigma}=\sqrt{0.93\cdot0.07}\approx0.255$ and you will reach a nice solution.

You need also to fix a Type I error ($\alpha$)

Example: fixing $\alpha=2.5\%$ you get that the one-tail CI is

$$[0.93;0.93+\frac{1.96}{10}0.255]=[0.93;0.98]$$

You cannot reject your null hypothesis as $0.95$ is included in the interval